# double genitive: a friend of hers

Tags: possessives

> (1) Do you know any friends **of hers**? 
>   (2) Do you know those friends **of hers**? 
>   (3) Do you know a friend **of hers**?

Both in (1) and (2), ‘*hers*’ seems to be ‘*her friends*.’ But in (3), is it ‘*her friend*’ or ‘*her friends*’? If ‘*of hers*’ has a meaning of ‘among the set of her friends,’ it would be the latter. While if it has a meaning of ‘that is her friend’, it would be the former. But this so called double genitive (CGEL,p.46, fn. 63) makes me wondered.

Comment: How could the meaning of (3) imply multiple friends? The word *friend* there is in the singular.

Comment: Why would "among the set of her friends" imply a plural? "first among equals" is "among a set of equals", but it is certainly singular. _One_ element from a set is still _one_ element, however big the set is.

Comment: I loved your comment @oerkelens

Comment: Note that these are both possible: *He is a friend of my dad's.*, *He is a friend of my dad.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to wonder there!

> This is my friend 
>  That is **yours**, and 
>  Here is **hers**.

Likewise...

> Friend of mine 
>  Friend of yours, and 
>  Friend of **hers**

**[Hers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hers)** -pronoun's possession.

> Do you know a friend of hers ~ Yes, I know a *friend of hers* (fit in the above example).

The sentence reads *a friend of...* and is singular. *Hers* there is as defined above.

Good points to note are CopperKettle's and Oerkelens'.